# Getting the last 20 hash items in Redis with O(1) time complexity?

Tags: hash, redis

Following the Redis suggestion that I must use hashes whenever possible:

> Small hashes are encoded in a very small space, so you should try
>   representing your data using hashes every time it is possible. For
>   instance if you have objects representing users in a web application,
>   instead of using different keys for name, surname, email, password,
>   use a single hash with all the required fields.

and that I'll be having millions items, I'm trying to store posts as hashes:

```
hmset post:1 title "hello"

hmset post:2 title "hi"

hmset post:3 title "g'day"
```

Now, I know I can retrieve a hash as easy as I created it:

```
hgetall post:1
```

The problem is that I want to retrieve more than one, possibly 20 in one row.

I tried the following command which didn't work (without the 3 dots of course):

```
hgetall post:1 post:2 post:3 post:4...
```

Giving the following error:

```
(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hgetall' command
```

I could do this client side:

```
hgetall post:1
```

then

```
hgetall post:2
```

and so on.. but that would be a **huge** waste of network resources and a potentially performance bottleneck as the system should be able to handle at least 5000 users/sec concurrently on average.

Failing what I did, what is the best way to accomplish this? Is there a way to send this commands one time instead of doing it sequentially? Is there a *lrange* type operation that can be made on hashes?

Comment: Lua or pipelining should help. Also this may be a sign that you need a real database.

Answer (score 1):

You are in the right direction - do your HGETALLs one after the other for each of the 20 posts. However, to save on network round trips, look into using Redis' pipelining that essentially allows you to group/batch your requests. Alternatively, you can achieve a similar result by implementing you own version of HGETALL that accepts multiple key names with a server-side Lua script.

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out it turns out you can use a **Pipelined** request to send multiple commands at once.

From [the Redis page dedicated to Pipelining](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining):

> A Request/Response server can be implemented so that it is able to
>   process new requests even if the client didn't already read the old
>   responses. This way it is possible to send multiple commands to the
>   server without waiting for the replies at all, and finally read the
>   replies in a single step.
>
> This is called pipelining, and is a technique widely in use since many
>   decades. For instance many POP3 protocol implementations already
>   supported this feature, dramatically speeding up the process of
>   downloading new emails from the server.

If I'm not wrong it is the same technique used by the **HMSET** command, which "Pipelines" multiple **HSET** commands.

A snippet from the Redis site shows an example with and without Pipelining using Ruby:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'redis'

def bench(descr)
    start = Time.now
    yield
    puts "#{descr} #{Time.now-start} seconds"
end

def without_pipelining
    r = Redis.new
    10000.times {
        r.ping
    }
end

def with_pipelining
    r = Redis.new
    r.pipelined {
        10000.times {
            r.ping
        }
    }
end

bench("without pipelining") {
    without_pipelining
}
bench("with pipelining") {
    with_pipelining
}
```

Go also has a client called Redigo, capable of command Pipelining:

```
// Initialize Redis (Redigo) client on port 6379 
//  and default address 127.0.0.1/localhost
client, err := redis.Dial("tcp", ":6379")
  if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
defer client.Close()

// Initialize Pipeline
client.Send("MULTI")

// Send writes the command to the connection's output buffer
client.Send("HGETALL", "post:1") // Where "post:1" contains " title 'hello' content 'hi' "

client.Send("HGETALL", "post:2") // Where "post:1" contains " title 'g'day' content 'g'mornin' "

// Execute the Pipeline
pipe_prox, err := client.Do("EXEC")

if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

log.Println(pipe_prox)
```

This is fine as long as you're comfortable showing non-string results.. I'm still trying to find a way to convert the result to strings, as of now I'm getting this:

```
[[[116 105 116 108 101] [104 105]] [[116 105 116 108 101] [104 101 108 108 111]]]
```

Doing the following doesn't help either:

```
result, _ := redis.Strings(pipe_prox, err)

log.Println(pipe_prox)
```

As this is what I get:

```
[]
```

I'll update this answer as soon as I manage to resolve this issue.